# XmlNode in XmlNodelist

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, youtube, namespaces

Does anyone know where is mistake? Or is better way to get video name into string?

```
string text = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><entry><title>VIDEO NAME</title></entry></feed>";
string xpath = "feed/entry";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(text);
XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes(xpath);
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string title = node["title"].InnerText;
    MessageBox.Show(title);
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
      <entry>
        <title>VIDEO NAME</title>
      </entry>
    </feed>
```

Comment: You could go right after the title with xpath = feed/entry/title and skip the lookup within the iteration  but what problem are you having?

Comment: Dont understand what yout meant. If i run code it doesnt show messagebox.

Comment: that part isn't clear in your question. It helps generate answers if you are very specific about what you expect your code to do and what it is doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration in the Xml `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'`  puts all elements in the document that don't have a namespace prefix in the default namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom/`. Therefore you need to use namespaces in your XPath queries:

```
        string text = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><entry><title>VIDEO NAME</title></entry></feed>";

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(text);
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        string xpath = "atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:title";
        XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes(xpath, nsmgr);

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: I was struggling with this problem, found this answer and it solved all my problems. Important to understand WHY one needs to implement this was my issue, now I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument and XPath:

```
string text = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><entry><title>VIDEO NAME</title></entry></feed>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
var atom = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

var titles = doc.Descendants(atom + "entry")
                .Select(e => (string)e.Element(atom + "title"))
                .ToList();

foreach (string title in titles)
    Console.WriteLine(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but the code I produced feels like such a dirty hack

```
        string text = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'><entry><title>VIDEO NAME</title></entry></feed>";
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(text);
        XmlNode parentNode = xml.GetElementsByTagName("feed").Item(0);
        foreach (XmlNode n in parentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            string title = n["title"].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(title);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```