# C# XML can no get sub-sub-sub node

Tags: c#, xml

i get a little complicated XML to fetch
it is like:

```
<Response xmlns="http://somewhere/somewhere/">
<Params>
<Param>
<Name>some data</Name>
<Value xmlns="">abcdedsfeesfxyz0123456789</Value>
</Param>
<Param>
<Name>Target</Name>
<Value xmlns="">xml</Value>
</Param>
<Param>
<Name>Platform</Name>
<Value xmlns="">Mobile</Value>
</Param>
</Params>
<Results>
<Groups>
<Group>
<Key>ABCWXYZ0123456789</Key>
<TotalCount>1208</TotalCount>
<Useful>...</Useful>
</Group>
</Groups>
</Results>
</Response>
```

the useful data for me is in the the  `<Useful>...</Useful>`

then i try to get the first layer:

```
    String returnXML = client.DownloadString(strUrl);
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(returnXML);
    XmlNode xmlData = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Response");
```

there is no  data in `xmlData`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Response element has a default namespace defined.

`<Response xmlns="http://somewhere/somewhere/">`

You will need to resolve this namespace in the XPath expression you pass to SelectSingleNode. You can accomplish this using a XmlNamespaceManager:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(returnXml);

var mng = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
mng.AddNamespace("foo", "http://somewhere/somewhere/");

XmlNode xmlData = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("foo:Response",mng);
```

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

hmmm

i find this works!

```
XmlNodeList myElemList = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("Usful");
```

Comment: That's because tag name doesn't take namespace into account. An Xml name has two parts; a namespace and a local name. Namespace can be empty. Much better to understand xml namespaces and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) because you have namespaces declared (this line `xmlns="http://somewhere/somewhere/"`).

See the answer to this question [XmlNode in XmlNodelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311194/xmlnode-in-xmlnodelist/15311404#15311404)

Understanding Xml namespaces will help you immensely. Try this article. http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm